# Cards won't be positionned correctly

Tags: html, css

Building a website with the framework Materialize.css and can't figure out how to get the cards to be properly positionned.

[card-unpositionned-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht4Uq.png)

I want the cards to be positionned right under the parallax part (where it says parallax as header with a short paragraph under it) inline (so they are not separated block by block).

Code snippet in index.html

```
<section style="display:inline;">
        <article class="card">
            <header class="card__thumb">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/370/235/2">
                </a>
            </header>
            <div class="card__date">
                <span class="card__date__day">12</span>
                <span class="card__date__month">May</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card__body">
                <div class="card__category"><a href="#">Photos</a></div>
                <h2 class="card__title"><a href="#">Bender Should Not Be Allowed on TV</a></h2>
                <div class="card__subtitle">A Head in the Polls</div>
                <p class="card__description">
                    With a warning label this big, you know they gotta be fun! This is the worst part. The calm before the battle. No! The cat shelter's on to me. Yes, I saw. You were doing well, until everyone died. Daylight and everything.
                </p>
            </div>
            <footer class="card__footer">
                <span class="icon icon--time"></span>6 min
                <span class="icon icon--comment"></span><a href="#">39 comments</a>
            </footer>
        </article>
        <article class="card">
            <header class="card__thumb">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/370/235/2">
                </a>
            </header>
            <div class="card__date">
                <span class="card__date__day">12</span>
                <span class="card__date__month">May</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card__body">
                <div class="card__category"><a href="#">Photos</a></div>
                <h2 class="card__title"><a href="#">Bender Should Not Be Allowed on TV</a></h2>
                <div class="card__subtitle">A Head in the Polls</div>
                <p class="card__description">
                    With a warning label this big, you know they gotta be fun! This is the worst part. The calm before the battle. No! The cat shelter's on to me. Yes, I saw. You were doing well, until everyone died. Daylight and everything.
                </p>
            </div>
            <footer class="card__footer">
                <span class="icon icon--time"></span>6 min
                <span class="icon icon--comment"></span><a href="#">39 comments</a>
            </footer>
        </article>
        </section>
```

Code in assets/css/style.css

```
* {


box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-color: #d8e0e5; }

.card {
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 370px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s; }
  .card a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none; }

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }

.card__date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #38c4a5;
  border-radius: 50%; }
  .card__date__day {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px; }
  .card__date__month {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase; }

.card__thumb {
  height: 235px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: height 0.3s; }
  .card__thumb img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); }
  .card:hover .card__thumb img {
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2); }
  .card:hover .card__thumb {
    height: 90px; }

.card__body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 185px;
  transition: height 0.3s; }
  .card:hover .card__body {
    height: 330px; }

.card__category {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #38c4a5; }

.card__title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold; }
  .card:hover .card__title {
    -webkit-animation: titleBlur 0.3s;
            animation: titleBlur 0.3s; }

.card__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #38c4a5; }
  .card:hover .card__subtitle {
    -webkit-animation: subtitleBlur 0.3s;
            animation: subtitleBlur 0.3s; }

.card__description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #666C74;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 27px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(25px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(25px);
          transform: translateY(25px); }
  .card:hover .card__description {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0); }

.card__footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #A3A9AB; }
  .card__footer .icon--comment {
    margin-left: 12px; }

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 2px; }

.icon--comment {
  background: url(https://www.grafikart.fr/demo/CSS3/cardui/img/icon-comment.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: -2px; }

.icon--time {
  background: url(https://www.grafikart.fr/demo/CSS3/cardui/img/icon-time.png);
  width: 10px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: -3px; }

@-webkit-keyframes titleBlur {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px transparent; } }

@keyframes titleBlur {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px transparent; } }

@-webkit-keyframes subtitleBlur {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(56, 196, 165, 0.6); }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(56, 196, 165, 0); } }

@keyframes subtitleBlur {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(56, 196, 165, 0.6); }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(56, 196, 165, 0); } }
```

Tried wrapping the cards with a section tag giving him a style of `display: inline` but didn't change the thing.

Here's a schema of how I would like it to work:

[schema-how-it-works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0upw.png)

Comment: The question is not very clear.. Could you put up an image of what you want too?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't post any image because I don't have enough reputation points so I'll give you the link of a schema of how I want it to look like http://i.imgur.com/TJhQoXv.png?1

Comment: You are using Materialize.css, so use grids : [Grid](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)